# How to read excel sheet with specific string into R

Tags: r, excel

I have thousands of excel file need to clean. I need to read the sheet with specific name and clean them. Most of the tabs' name are in something like 'EQuote', but there are some tabs are in the name of 'E-Quote' or 'EQuote' with some additional words. However, all the tabs' name contain 'Quote'. Can you help me on read the excel tab into dataframe when the tab's name contains 'Quote'.

My code is like this, but this can only read the excel sheet named in 'EQuote'.

```
whole_data <- lapply(file.list, function(file){
    df= read_excel(file, sheet = 'EQuote')

    ....my clean steps....
})
```

How can I change the code to read the sheets, which name contains string 'Quote'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list all sheets in an excel file with `readxl::excel_sheets` then filter to only names containing "Quote" with `grepl()` (set `ignore.case = TRUE` if there is a mix of cases in the sheet names).

```
sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(file)
quote_sheets <- sheets[grepl("Quote", sheets, ignore.case = FALSE)]
```

Answer (score 0):

So maybe you can try this. First of all get all the sheet names in a variable:

```
library(openxlsx)
Names <- getSheetNames('file_path')
```

Afterwards you simply filter for the names to contain only the string you need

```
Names_good <- Names[grepl('Quote', Names)]
```

And you do a for loop

```
library(readxl)
for(i in 1:length(Names_good)){
df <- read_excel("file_path", sheet = paste0(Names_good[i])

....your clean steps and output....

}
```